# MVC PartialViews models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to use a different model for my partialviews, how to do this?  Do you have examples?

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">first tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">second tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">third tab</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("FirstTabView", Model)}
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("SecondTabView", Model)}
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("ThirdTabView", Model)}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need a view model containing properties for each of the models you want to pass to the partials, then `@{Html.RenderPartial("FirstTabView", Model.Model1Property)}`

Comment: Do you have access to the "Other" model?

Comment: Another option is to use EditorTemplate. http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have sub-models as part of your main model, such as:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public FirstTabModel FirstTab { get; set; }
    public SecondTabModel SecondTab { get; set; }
    public ThirdTabModel ThirdTab { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("FirstTabView", Model.FirstTab)}
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("SecondTabView", Model.SecondTab)}
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("ThirdTabView", Model.ThirdTab)}
</div>
```